# Rails: wkhtmltopdf executable in the wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge gem is being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf

I am working on a **Rails** application on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

I used the [wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge), [wkhtmltopdf](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf), [wkhtmltopdf-binary](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary), [wkhtmltopdf-heroku](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-heroku) gems to convert **HTML** to **PDF**.

I defined it this way in my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'wicked_pdf'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'
end 

group :production do
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
end
```

Everything was working fine until recently when I started encountering this error whenever I try to run `bundle install`:

> Error: The wkhtmltopdfexecutable in thewkhtmltopdf-binary-edge gem is being loaded, but it's also present in other gems (wkhtmltopdf-binary). If you meant to run the executable for another gem, make sure you use a project specific binstub (bundle binstub ). If you plan to use multiple conflicting executables, generate binstubs for them and disambiguate their names.

I have tried a couple of solutions, but none seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's how I solved**:

It seemed like gems `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge` and `wkhtmltopdf-binary` have conflicting executables.

I simply had to remove the `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge` gem and re-ordered the `Gemfile` this way:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'


group :production do
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**